Authenticity of a hadith regarding hazrat ali cursing hz muawiya
Is musannaf ibne abi shayba 7123 authentic and whats the explanation like who callled this authentic

Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaybah 7123 does not lead to any hadith related to Muawiyah in any edition I looked at. But, I imagine this question is referring to 7232.

This is the narration:

حَدَّثَنَا هُشَيْمٌ، قَالَ: أَخْبَرَنَا حُصَيْنٌ، قَالَ: حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ مَعْقِلٍ، قَالَ: صَلَّيْتُ مَعَ عَلِيٍّ صَلَاةَ الْغَدَاةِ، قَالَ: فَقَنَتَ، فَقَالَ فِي قُنُوتِهِ: «اللَّهُمَّ عَلَيْكَ بِمُعَاوِيَةَ وَأَشْيَاعِهِ، وَعَمْرِو بْنِ الْعَاصِ وَأَشْيَاعِهِ، وَأَبِي السُّلَمِيِّ وَأَشْيَاعِهِ، وَعَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ قَيْسٍ وَأَشْيَاعِهِ»

According to the editors of this edition of the Musannaf, this hadith is Sahih.
The following is a translation of it:

Abdurrahman ibn Ma'qal said: I prayed Isha with Ali (RA) and he did qunoot and said in the qunoot, "O Allah, deal with Muawiyah and his groups, and Amr ibn al-Aas and his groups, and Abu Al-A'war as-Sulami and his groups, and Abdullah ibn Qais and his groups."

The phrase اللهم عليك literally means "upon you is XYZ." It is used to ask Allah to deal with a group. It is not a curse in the normal sense of the word but it can encompass a curse if that is the intention of the speaker. It can also just refer to dealing with them in the world and helping you against them.
